# How do i identify whether a new field(text field , input field etc) is added on a webpage? through ruby script

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have a Webpage to automate , and each run if a new field is being added on the webpage, how do i get notified from my script that a new field is being added and fail my current script?

(iam using Ruby2.4 and watir 5.0)

Comment: Which field? Textfield or select list?

Comment: I would count all fields on that page and store that number in a constant. When the number doesn't match when the script is running then raise an exception. What did you try so far? Please show your code. What problem do you face?

Comment: Please give an example, how do the fields on the webpage look like? (code-wise)

Comment: please provide some sample HTML and the code you've tried so far.   at the moment we don't have enough details to offer much more than general advice.

Answer (score 0):

first of all take all the elements into an array

```
arr=@b.elements.map{|x| x.id}
p arr
```

If you checking specifically for textfield, then

```
arr=@b.text_fields.map{|x| x.id}
p arr
```

Now your console has all the elements id.

Then create this array

```
array=<<_.lines.map(&:chomp)
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
_
```

and then whenever you check your elements against these elements, You would easily come to know if elements are missing or added.

```
missingElements=array-@b.elements.map{|x| x.id}

addedElements=@b.elements.map{|x| x.id}-array
```